# Should get and Post requests be in separate angular services

Tags: angular, architecture, angular-services

I am wondering if separating angular services for post request and get request is a good angular coding practice ?
Basically the question is the following, you have an api that returns a list of objects, the same api accepts a post request to add a new object in the database. Should the get and post methods be in the same service, or should they be separated in two distinct services.

Comment: Opinion based, but personally I see no reason to break them up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It wouldn't make sense in my opinion to separate requests based on their method type unless the nature of the application you are developing would benefit from such an approach.

What I have seen mostly is that you keep requests that act on a certain resource in a common service. For instance, if you had a service called `UserService`, it would contain all the requests required for `User` CRUD, i.e.,

- `GET users` (gets the list of all the users)
- `GET users/:id` (gets the user with `id`)
- `POST users` (creates a user)
- `DELETE users/:id` (deletes the user with `id`)
- `PATCH/PUT users/:id` (updates the user with `id`)

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question precisely: No, it is not a good angular coding practice to split an service for api calls into two separate services for get- and post-requests. You can't find it in the angular docs and I never worked on a project that did that. But if it fits into your project (which I doubt), then of course you can do it.